# JSON POST on iOS with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ios, json, flask

Inside my flask python web program, I save a few parameters in SessionStorage in order to send them back to flask, then save this information as a txt file.

For some reason, everything works flawlessly on PC and Android, couldn't get it to work on iOS devices. it recognizes and saves the sessionStorgae elements before sending, but no txt file is created afterwards (at the end of the app).

Client-side (HTML):

```js
function func()
{
...
    $.ajax({
    url: "{{ url_for('getInfo', _external=True) }}",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    accepts: {
     json: 'application/json',
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(log)
});
       return;

...
}
```

```html
 <form id = "myForm" name ="myForm"  method="post" action="{{url_for('final')}}" onsubmit="return func()">
```

Server-side (Flask):

```
@app.route("/get_info",methods = ['POST'])
def getInfo():
    list = request.get_json()
    global id
    with open(id + '.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
            json.dump(list,outfile,indent=2)
    return 'OK'
```

I can't figure out the solution. Also I can't remember if it used to work or not on iOS. trying to run all kinds of tests as I'm writing this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

If you believe more information is needed, I elaborated in the comments about the overall structure of that HTML page and web program.

Comment: Is your protocol scheme is `http` or `https`?

Comment: my protocol is https.

Comment: you should post `objc` or  `swift` code partial.

Comment: Not using any. it's a web-app. sorry for misclarification

Comment: Add a `print` before and after you save the file - just to make sure the 'getInfo()' is activated.

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't show anything, which means it doesn't let this function to be activated. However, I printed the information as a pop-up, so collecting it works as intends. for some reason, it won't run this - probably something related to ajax and iOS browser's restrictions? Again, this works on both Android and Windows.

Comment: I'll try to elaborate about this HTML page, in case more info might help: It contains a form with a few text areas, which the user submits. As he presses submit, the form fires the "func" (the onsubmit). "func" checks the answers, and if they're correct - calls "getInfo" in flask, sending the SessionStorage saved element. After all this ends, the "action" field in the form goes, and activates "final" function in flask, which appends the user-id variable to the log file. This function works in all platforms.

Comment: I divided these two operations into different functions because I needed to do both as submit button is pressed, but it won't let me add my Session Storage element into the form. Once the form is submitted, I can no longer add anything to the function handling it on the flask side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for future readers:
iOS puts ajax request in cache. which later on might give empty response, or don't trigger the function at all. you can solve that by adding a few parameters and headers to the ajax request, which will prevent it from happenning:

```
cache: false,
processData: false,
async: true,
headers: {
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in 'DEBUG' mode

```
@app.route("/get_info",methods = ['POST'])
def getInfo():
    list = request.get_json()
    global id
    file_name = '{}.txt'.format(id)
    print('About to write {} to file {}'.format(str(list),file_name))
    with open(file_name, 'w+') as outfile:
            json.dump(list,outfile,indent=2)
    print('Data was written')
    return 'OK'
```